# batch file - sqlcmd failing in scheduled tasks (0x2331)

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, sqlcmd

I'm trying to use scheduled tasks to run a database back up once per day using sqlcmd that points to a SQL script.

If I open a command prompt and run the code in the batch file everything is successful but when task manager tries it gets a 0x2331 error.

A search reveals it's something to do with permissions - maybe I need to change the path to the sql file?

here is the script:

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO This is running to backup a database
sqlcmd -S COMPNAME -i C:\backup.sql
GO
ECHO Success!
EXIT
```

I'm new to batch files to tried to keep it as simple as possble.

Comment: `"I'm trying to use task manager..."` Do you mean scheduled tasks?  Assuming so, does the account the task is running as have the correct access?

Comment: Is this SQL Server Express so you have no other choice but to use scheduled tasks? Because for any other edition, this is the sort of thing you let SQL Server Agent handle with a scheduled job.

Comment: my bad. - yes scheduled tasks sorry!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately yes this is SQL Server Express

Comment: @squillman - It's running as the Administrator account so I would have thought everything was good

Comment: @MichaelHarper Not necessarily.  SQL Server does not add the administrator account by default (unless you manually provisioned it during installation or afterward).  Double check the database permissions and make sure that account has access to the database, or change the scheduled task to run under an account that does.

Comment: @squillman I just checked the database - COMPNAME\Administrator is listed in Logins and it runs fine from a command prompt :(

Comment: Where is the backup being saved to? Where is the `GO` command located?  Is the task configured to run whether user is logged on or not?

Comment: @Squashman this is the sql command sqlcmd runs (note, this works as expected from cmd propmpt / SSMS) it backs up the db to Azure: BACKUP DATABASE [db] TO  URL = N'https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/databasebackups/backup.bak' WITH FORMAT, CREDENTIAL = N'backup-cred', 
 NAME = N'db-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
Task is configured to run whether logged in or not.